# Finding distribution function for a r.v. X such that X(t) = t

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I was going through Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes by Papoulis and Pillai when I got stuck in example 4-5.

> A telephone call occurs at random in the interval (0, 1). In this experiment. the
> outcomes are time distances t between 0 and 1 and the probability that t is between t1
> and t2 is given by
> $$P \{t_1\le t \le t_2\} = t_2-t_1 $$
> We define the random variable X such that
> $$X(t) = t \quad (0\le t \le 1)$$

As for the part what I do and don't understand, I think in terms of simpler experiments such as a coin toss I get the gist that r.v is supposed to be a set of the experimental outcomes and also the intuitive sense of how the CDF should be. I imagine the individual probabilities of (H,T) as a Dirac Delta function and the CDF to be their summation. However I do lack the exact mathematical framework to proceed with the question in this as well as the coin toss problem.

Comment: It may help to emphasize that this is telling you $$P[\{\omega \in [0,1] : t_1\leq \omega \leq t_2\}] = t_2 - t_1$$ whenever $t_1, t_2$ satisfy $0\leq t_1\leq t_2\leq 1$. Equivalently, $P[[t_1, t_2]] = t_2-t_1$. So it is not giving you probabilities for _all_ of the subsets of the sample space, it is only giving you probabilities for subsets that happen to be intervals.  But from that you can infer other probabilities.  For example you know $P[[1/8, 2/8]]$ and $P[[6/8,7/8]]$ so you can infer $P[[1/8, 2/8] \cup [6/8, 7/8]]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a random variable is just a (measurable) mapping, or function, from the sample space to the real numbers. In this experiment, the sample space is being modeled as the real numbers between 0 and 1, $[0,1]$, and $X: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is set to be $X(t) = t$. The information about the probability associated to subsets of the sample space, i.e. $P(t_1 \le t \le t_2 ) = t_2 -t_1$ is sufficient to describe the CDF of $X$ (what is it?).

Imagining random variables, or their CDFs, as being (finite) summations of Dirac functions is useful when the sample space is finite, but is harder to work with when the sample space is infinite, and especially when the sample space is uncountable (as in this example). It turns out all random variables and their CDF's can be imagined as limits of such summations of Dirac functions, but this is not necessarily the most "compact" way of thinking about random variables/CDF's in general.